# How to limit a Firestore query limit using another value from a Firestore document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We have a SaaS solution for gyms and fitness.

There are 3 plans and each gym is subscribed to one. The first plans allows up to 50 members and is free, the second 50 to 500 members and costs $x and the third 500+ members and is $y. The plans and how many members they allow are stored in a collection in Firestore.

We have Firestore security rules that blocks requests with more than the plan's allowed number of members. That is because a gym could upgrade to the second plan and add 150 members and then downgrade to free. In this case can only request 50 members once again.

Even though the security rule works like a charms it is not clear to us how to implement this correctly in the client. The client is a Vue.js website. After the website loads, the gym's members are requested from Firestore and stored into Vuex. When requesting more than allowed there is a permission insufficient message that is totally expected.

The problem is with the limit on the firestore request on the client side. The number of allowed members corresponds to the plan the gym is subscribed to that is stored on Firestore. It looks like we have to request this before we request the gyms members. So we need 1. the gyms plan name 2. plan members allowance and then 3. the gym's members.

We are pretty skeptical about this as it requires 3 requests for something that it is meant to be straightforward. We don't mind the costs of the request rather that the tradeoff of waiting 3 roundtrip requests.

```
`let membersLimit = this.$store.state.stripePlans[this.$store.state.gymProfilePrivate.stripePlan].membersCount
firestore.collection('_gyms').doc(gymId).collection('_members')
.limit(membersLimit)
.onSnapshot(docs => {
    let members = []
    docs.forEach(doc => {
        let member = doc.data()
        members.push(member)
        this.$store.commit('updateGymMembers', members)
    })
    //do stuff with members
})`
```

Things we are considering so far.

1. Request the first 50 members that are always allowed and when and if plans are update, request the total number of members in the gyms plan
2. Wait for plans and gym plan info and then request gym members
3. Create a cloud function to request gym members and disable access to gym members from the client side

Comment: I recommend you to make a Plans collection, with a Document for each plan storing the total members, you count the total members via cloud function listeners, otherwise you would have to make 50+ reads each page visit, instead you only have 1 read and get the same result, otherwise I wasnt able to see your exact question?

Comment: The question was unclear. I rewrote it.